# Why hadoop yarn mapreduce job not working and stop on running job?

Tags: hadoop, memory, mapreduce, jobs, hadoop-yarn

I have a mapreduce job and I ran it with YARN mode. But why my mapreduce job stop and not continue while running job step? It's like this :

```
15/04/04 17:18:21 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1428142358448_0002
15/04/04 17:18:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1428142358448_0002/
15/04/04 17:18:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1428142358448_0002
```

And that's stop here. Is because lack of memory? After start-all.sh and all daemon have started, I have about 300-350 MB memory. I need your suggest all, why this happened?

Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't because of out of memory, else the logs would have clearly mentioned that. The job seems to be in running state and has got stuckup somewhere, you can probably go and check on the application master for more details about the job.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, so how can I check and fix that? Is this wrong configuration or something else?

Comment: Its hard to say as of now. Could you send me a screenshot of the syslogs of the job : job_1428142358448_0002. That might be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean with syslog? Am I able to send picture through comment? I've try to tweak on yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml but it's nothing. Thanks....

Comment: When you see the job running n the Application Master, you can view the logs of the running jobs. Leave aside screenshot, just copy-paste the logs here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but you mean this thing ?

```
15/04/05 14:11:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/04/05 14:11:29 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.1.163:8050
15/04/05 14:11:30 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/04/05 14:11:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/04/05 14:11:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1428216622742_0003
15/04/05 14:11:31 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1428216622742_0003
15/04/05 14:11:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1428216622742_0003/
15/04/05 14:11:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1428216622742_0003
```

or something else? on my master node port 8088 there are only tables....